# How can I return empty the snapshot docs of firebase without returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I just directly go to the code. Basically let say I have a carts and orders...The carts and orders should be in the item of a certain "email". Now what I want to do since my snapshot carts and orders loop around its item and some of its email is not the same whose email is login. I wonder how can I return empty the **carts and orders** if the login account has no yet "carts or orders" without returning "undefined" item.

```
onSnapshot(orderCollectionRef,snapshot => {
  // snapshot.docs.map((doc_,idx) => {
  //   if (doc_.data().email == currentUser?.email) {
  //     setOrders(prevState => [...prevState,doc_.data()])
  //   }
  // })
  setOrders(snapshot.docs.map((doc_,idx) => {
    if (doc_.data().email == currentUser?.email) {
      return {
        ...doc_.data()
      }
    } else {
      return null 
    }
  }))
})
```

As you see I have a `doc_.data().email == currentUser?.email` because it is inside the authentication email...now since the `orders` have different located emails in their cart.. I wonder how to not make `const [orders,setOrders] = useState([])` not have a list of `undefined` cause this is what returning at when their is no user login or there is no item in `orders and carts`...
You see also in the `comment tags` that those are most valid that do not return `undefined` since it was a push array,but it was not useful cause it is not `removing the arrays when I update new carts` rather it just make the call twice...basically what I mean here( I am talking too much) is

```
setOrders(snapshot.docs.map((doc_,idx) => {
  if (doc_.data().email == currentUser?.email) {
    return {
      ...doc_.data()
    }
  } else {
    // What should will return here???
    // return null 
  }
}))
```

How do I make this return just empty just none if there is no email that in the list of `snapshot of carts and orders`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to filter out the items without a matching email address, and then only map the remaining ones, which you can do with [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
setOrders(snapshot.docs
  .filter((doc_) => doc_.data().email == currentUser?.email)
  .map((doc_) => doc_.data());
}))
```